# Is it valid to knowingly repost an existing (fixed) bug report as a question on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I've answered a very interesting question recently. I couldn't find any other resource about the issue, even after half an hour of searching.

The question has received another answer (after mine) that links to an existing bug report about the issue. The bug has been already fixed.

Another user has made the observation that the question and the bug report are *very* similar. It might be even the case that the asker has knowingly reposted the bug report.

I can only imagine two reasons for that:

- Reputation. This would be obviously a questionable motivation.
- Getting an understandable answer. Bug reports might state the problem but might be very technical and hard to understand. The corresponding solution or fix might be also very technical and hard to understand.

So here is the question: Is it valid to knowingly repost an existing (fixed) bug report as a question on Stack Overflow?

<sub>I'm not linking the question in .. question because I don't want the user to get meta-effected. It's an interesting question that shows an interesting (but faulty) behaviour of a programming language. It got many upvotes but is unfortunately very similar to an existing bug report.</sub>

Comment: maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65854898/8620333 ? you don't want meta effect but we need to know the use case to have more details

Comment: @TemaniAfif Well, I guess it's hard to keep secret when people can simply visit my profile and look for the most recent answer. But yeah: it's that one.

Comment: I don't see the issue. What could be wrong to post a bug report as answer? Saying that what you are facing is *bug* is a valid answer

Comment: @TemaniAfif Not as an answer. As a question.

Comment: I observed that the 2 recent Java questions are about bugs that have been reported.

Comment: @akuzminykh it would be great if you could include a screenshot in your question. It is hard to tell otherwise. You can of course edit out the user card.

Comment: it is ok, to ask another community if there is no sufficient answer, so the timing is crucial, but as you said youcouldn't find it yourself, so it looks ok to me

Comment: "the question and the bug report are similar". In what way? Creating MCVE for a bug is quite likely to lead to similar code. Is there anything that seems to indicate the code from the bug report was copied?

Comment: Well at least OP tried to hide the copy job by renaming the classes and variables, but I guess they don't understand the purpose of `_` in numerical literals, so they converted `50_000` to `2000_0` instead of `20_000` (or they understood that it can be placed almost anywhere and just used it randomly in order to hide the previously mentioned copy).

Comment: @MartinSmith in a way that seems strange. I can't think of a normal use case where one would create a loop that runs 2000 times a while statement with an empty block that during its condition increments other variable.

Comment: I think it's easy to focus on the person and miss the bigger picture. Sure someone might start posting questions based on bug reports for quick upvotes, but the majority of people who genuinely encounter the bug are more likely to google their way to a stackoverflow question rather than a bug report. In that sense regardless of the motivation of the original poster, if the question and answer end up helping people, then it's an overall good outcome

Comment: It saddens me to see it stated repeatedly that doing something purely to earn reputation is a "questionable motive". Do I like that the current system *requires* me to earn reputation in order to get privileges to curate the site more effectively? No, but I'm also unaware of an alternative to getting those privileges other than via earning reputation points. Given that the current system values reputation as much as it does, it looks very clear to me why several (but not all) users are motivated to gain reputation, and I see nothing remotely "questionable" in those motives.

Comment: @apokryfos Exactly, bug reports are hardly accessible: In very technical contexts they tend to be hard to understand and hard to find on top. Therefore it's absolutely valid to repost bug fixes (and get them explained) to make them more accessible to a wider audience. However, it should be done on a case-to-case basis. I'm against reposting every minor tweak or whatever.

Comment: @eis I'd wager the bug was found via fuzzing and then manually reduced to a simpler form. Which makes it even more suspicious that the OP claims to have stumbled upon this on accident.

Comment: It could also be that someone else has taken the code from the bug report, modified it a  bit and given it as a challenge to the asker. Failing to figure out the challenge, he asks on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @cigien "...users are motivated to gain reputation, and I see nothing remotely "questionable" in those motives..." It's gamification and I'd say that gamification has advantages and disadvantages. It's not purely good.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's only OK to do this if you answer your own question immediately (you have a check-box to do that): if you already know the answer, don't waste other people's time. Also, make sure your answer is useful, and some other person will not have to write another answer to replace yours.

If you discovered a fix independently, see if it's better than the official fix, and post the best. In any case, post a link to an official bug report, and don't plagiarize.

Also, please don't do this a lot. We don't need to repost all bug reports on all software tools here: it would be boring to read, and will make the site useless. Post only questions (and answers) which you think are likely to help someone else.

Comment: Just as a comment " Post only questions (and answers) which you think are likely to help someone else." I believe that many people unfortunately aren't doing that. Still, it's really good advice.

Answer (score 10):

I would say there is a 3rd option: the OP is posting the question to make the answer more accessible.  I would consider that a valid reason to post the question here.  You spent a half hour searching and didn’t find an answer and then spent what looks like a considerable amount of time trying to post a helpful answer.  Next time someone has this problem and searches for it, it might be found in seconds....

Comment: As I commented at another answer: Why did OP then go down the path of altering the original code from the bug report? Also, he should have posted the answer then too.

Comment: So they wanted to make the bug report more accessible by plagiarizing it and obfuscating the origin? I fail to understand the reasoning here.

Comment: If you ask about a bug report and you are aware of it, you should link to it in the question. Then voters can judge the usefulness of that extra bit of accessibility. Otherwise people might be tricked into thinking it's something completely new. That would be dishonest.

Answer (score 4):

> Another user has made the observation that the question and the bug report are very similar. It might be even the case that the asker has knowingly reposted the bug report.

Might be, might not be. Who would know.

> I can only imagine two reasons for that: ...

In case the asker did not knowingly repost the bug report I can think of one additional reason: coincidence. The asker discovered the bug and was unaware of the bug report.

> Is it valid to knowingly repost an existing (fixed) bug report as a question on Stack Overflow?

It's difficult to know if somebody knowingly reposted an existing bug report, so I foresee some practical problems here.

In my mind, Stack Overflow is building a library of knowledge in the Q&A format. Quite a lot of knowledge that is also existing elsewhere is containing here, especially in simple, popular questions. And I guess that often enough, the askers here did not check that carefully to avoid asking a question that isn't already answered elsewhere. Duplicating knowledge will happen inevitably. And it's okay for important knowledge that is used often. Sometimes answers here can be better and a bit of competition doesn't hurt.

Having said that, askers are required to search for existing information and to present that research. It follows that there is no question left really if you already link to the solution in your question. Intentionally asking just for the sake of asking without any need for an answer (because there is already one) is just a waste of time. Yours and that of the expert answerers, and that time is precious. Don't do it.

Just because of unsuccessful or insufficient research we already get lots of duplicate questions (external duplicates that have been answered elsewhere, but also internal duplicates).

Comment: Could you clarify your last statement? So long as the rules are being followed, why shouldn't I do something just for reputation points? After all, according to the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), "*The more reputation you earn, the more privileges you gain and the more tools you'll have access to on the site*". Some of these privileges let me do things like curate content on the site more effectively. That seems to be a valid reason to want to earn more reputation points. Why shouldn't I, for example, answer a question *solely* because it give me these privileges?

Comment: @cigien You're right. There is a purpose in those reputation points. So if your goal is to do more curation on this site and you need more reputation for that, you can surely ask and answer a lot of questions. To me, reputation points were always more like a distraction. I consciously try to not think about them. The goal is to build a knowledge base and that's what counts. Rep is only a side product, not the main product of the activities here. However, this is only my opinion, so I will remove the last paragraph. Thanks for commenting on it.

Comment: @cigien I've tried to focus more on this with my question: When someone participates *only* for reputation, which means that they are *not* interested in posting high-quality content, don't they *tend* to post lower-quality content? And isn't that problematic? Specifically when users repost interesting bug reports: When a question clearly demonstrates a bug in a programming language, it attracts a ton of upvotes. Users can abuse that and my intention is to thematize it.

Comment: @akuzminykh Users cannot really abuse that if they are honest. A question that says "look there is this bug, it's already known and has attracted a fix" will hardly gain upvotes. What you would need is actually malicious intent (knowingly leaving out relevant information) and that would be difficult to prove. It could be seen as a disadvantage of gamification though.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Note that it's perfectly fine to have an opinion that reputation points don't, or shouldn't, matter. I was simply asking for clarification on that statement since it seemed to be making an absolute claim without sufficient justification. In fact, your comment responding to me does add those qualifications, and as such I think would be a nice addition to the answer itself.

Answer (score -3):

Caveats first. Before jumping to judgement, make sure you understand the
situation. It's possible that someone asked the question both places at the same
time, or maybe asked somewhere else first, then waited a while, and asked again
on Stack Overflow.

So it's possible that after the Stack Overflow question is posted, and after your
answer, **but before** the second answer, the question on the original site is
answered. This is not far-fetched: this exact situation has happened to me
several times. Sometimes I will shotgun a question across multiple sites. Some
might say this is a dubious practice; that's their opinion.

At any rate, if in fact my situation here matches what actually happened in your
case, then I say, no harm no foul.

But, if all the above is wrong, and in fact the offsite question was already
answered before anything on Stack Overflow, that's bad. It would be one thing if
the person got an answer offsite, and then paid it forward by posting an answer
on Stack Overflow. But to just post the question again for "reasons"? No.

Comment: in this case the offsite question was dealt with over a year ago before the question to SO was posted.

Answer (score -4):

Another valid reason to post a bug report (fixed or not) in a Q&A form on SO: **make the bug report easier to find on the web**.

Of course, if this is the reason, the answer should be posted immediately after the question - the checkbox to answer your own question is right there at the bottom of the "ask a question" form:

[image: Answer your own question]

Some bug reports have text or titles that are harder for search engines to find. Often, the bug report will list the root cause of the issue and will be developer-oriented. In this case, a SO post can list the more frequent error message that the users actually encounter more often.

**EXAMPLE:**
Post on Biostars (Q&A site similar to SO for bioinformatics): [Question: Samtools problem with running (Conda)](https://www.biostars.org/p/362263/)
Bug report: [samtools on macosx is incompatible with ncurses from defaults channel · Issue #13488 · bioconda/bioconda-recipes](https://github.com/bioconda/bioconda-recipes/issues/13488)

Comment: This would be one thing. But why did OP go the down the path of altering the original code from the bug report? Also, he should have posted the answer then too.

Answer (score -13):

Since Stack Overflow was *created* with a little bit of gamification in mind, I don't think we can get too worked up over someone actually playing the *game*. As long as the question is not a duplicate, and is on-topic, etc., then the fact that they are leveraging the bug for unicorn points is beside the point.

Besides, it would most likely only work if they were the first out of the gate with it (depending on which tag the question is in, and the gold-badge holders in that tag).